# How to make round corner in both sides of stroke in shape xml

Tags: android, android-shape

I tried to create a shape like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners android:radius="0.5dp"></corners>
  <stroke
    android:width="@dimen/strokeWidth"
    android:color="@color/mycolor"/>
  <solid android:color="@color/transparent"></solid>
</shape>
```

This is what I got:

[image: Round corner part]

Can I make the inner corner round as the outer border (now it's square)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some changes in your code and your output is ready :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="30dp"></corners> <!-- change this -->
    <stroke
        android:width="20dp"
        android:color="@color/black"/>
</shape>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: you're right. I found out that I need to make the corners bigger than the stroke.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="30dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
            <corners android:radius="40dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**output :-**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this,
**abc.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="-10dp"
        android:left="-10dp"
        android:right="-10dp"
        android:top="-10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**layout.xml**

```
android:background="@drawable/abc"
```